# Why do i need to write (answers[random.randint(0, len(answers) - 1)] instead of random.choice?

Tags: python

Hello everyone I learned the basics of python.
I wanted to start a project on a magic8ball.
It didn't worked so I searched a bit and found a working code.
He uses this weird thing and I don't know why.
Can someone explain what this means?

Comment: Absolutely no way for us to answer this without seeing the code.

Comment: You couldnt use `random.choiche`, though, because that's a typo

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Helpful may be ["how to ask good questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Users here are way more ready to help if you provide [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with some input and the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

`choice()` returns a random item from a list, tuple, or string while `randint()` returns a pseudorandom integer between a and b. You can use either, assuming you are passing it the right parameters.
Say you have

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

import random
random.choice(a)     # will return a random number from that list
random.randint(1,7)  # will return a random number between 1 and 7  itself
```

In your case,

```
answers[randint(0, len(answers) - 1)]
```

will give you a random integer between 0 and however long the list of answers is minus one.